# "ImportError: cannot import name util" Error on Google Drive SDK Quickstart Example

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I'm getting the following error message when attempting the Google Drive SDK Quickstart Example (https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 6, in <module>
    from apiclient.discovery import build
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/apiclient/discovery.py", line 45, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/apiclient/errors.py", line 26, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name util
```

As explained in the tutorial, first on my Mac terminal I:

```
easy_install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

I'm using a Mac OS 10.7.4 python 2.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `pip` instead of `easy_install`. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40955055/305689) to a similar question, it's likely that the Client Library and `oauth2client` libraries are incompatible. Best to upgrade both with `pip install -U google-api-python-client` (or `pip3` for Python 3).

After you get the quickstart working, if you want to see slightly longer, more "real-world" examples of using the Drive API, here are some videos and blog posts I made for you:

- [Listing your files in Google Drive](http://youtu.be/Z5G0luBohCg?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq&index=4) and code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2014/11/authorized-google-api-access-from-python.html)
- [Google Drive: Uploading & Downloading Files](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/01/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html) plus "Poor man's plain text to PDF converter" code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/12/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html) (*)
- Exporting a Google Sheet as CSV blog [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/07/exporting-google-sheet--as-csv.html) only

(*) - TL;DR: upload plain text file to Drive, import/convert to Google Docs format, then export that Doc as PDF. Post above uses Drive API v2; [this follow-up post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/12/migrating-to-new-google-drive-api-v3.html) describes migrating it to Drive API v3, and here's a [developer video](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/01/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html) combining both "poor man's converter" posts.